# Selected Tab on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a tabbed web page and i need to get to the selected tab when i refresh the web page...

I have tried but no success..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjarP/)...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // When a link is clicked
    $("a.tab").click(function () {


        // switch all tabs off
        $(".active").removeClass("active");

        // switch this tab on
        $(this).addClass("active");

        // slide all content up
        $(".content").slideUp();

        // slide this content up
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#"+content_show).slideDown();
    });
});
```

Comment: use cookies to store the active tab and use it.

Comment: Could you update the given fiddle??

Comment: The issue is JavaScript is a client side language and when you refresh the page the browser i.e. client re-runs the same script and it starts back at the default. So the solution would be storing a cookie or some other constant in a server language like PHP or ASP.NET to track which tab should be active

Comment: In this case, jsfiddle is not the best example because it doesn't update the url when clicking on a specific tab (which is how you keep track of which tab is selected without using javascript or anything else.)

Comment: You can find plenty of answers on Google. I suggest searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using cookie plugin from https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
var prevActiveTab = $.cookie("activeTabIndex");

$("a.tab").removeClass("active");
var $oldActive = $("a.tab").eq(prevActiveTab).addClass("active");
$(".content").slideUp();
var content_show = $oldActive.attr("title");
$("#"+content_show).slideDown();

// When a link is clicked
$("a.tab").click(function () {

$.cookie("activeTabIndex",$("a.tab").index($(this)));
// switch all tabs off
$(".active").removeClass("active");

// switch this tab on
$(this).addClass("active");

// slide all content up
$(".content").slideUp();

// slide this content up
var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
$("#"+content_show).slideDown();

});
```

What is done here, when tab is changed cookie is modified with `index` of active tab element. On page refresh, get that index and set class to `active` and remove other classes as well.

**UPDATE**
As the amount of data that need to stored is very less, you can opt-in for cookie approach instead of localstorage. Browser compatibility is also the issue if you want to target IE < 8.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:-

right now i am storing preference in the `localstorage`.

[See Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) for DOM storage options. But cookie might be a safe option in your case or store it in the server.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sH23W/)

#### storage Logic

```
 if (localStorage.activeTab) {//see if a tab has been stored in the localStorage

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(".tabs li:nth-child(" + (parseInt(localStorage.activeTab, 10) + 1) + ")  a.tab").addClass('active'); //Select that tab based on preference.
   }


localStorage.activeTab = $(this).parent().index(); //Store the tab in the storage.
```

#### Full Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    if (localStorage.activeTab) {//see if a tab has been stored in the localStorage

        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(".tabs li:nth-child(" + (parseInt(localStorage.activeTab, 10) + 1) + ")  a.tab").addClass('active'); //Select that tab based on preference.
    }
    // When a link is clicked
    $("a.tab").click(function () {


        // switch all tabs off
        $(".active").removeClass("active");

        // switch this tab on
        $(this).addClass("active");
        localStorage.activeTab = $(this).parent().index(); //Store the tab in the storage.
        // slide all content up
        $(".content").slideUp();

        // slide this content up
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#" + content_show).slideDown();
    });
});
```